# How to get the regularexpression for Dash and Numbers

Tags: asp.net, regex

In asp.net, I want to use regularexpressionvalidator for phone number. requirement is only to allow numbers and Dash (-)

```
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPhone"
                        ErrorMessage="Not a Valid Phone Number" ValidationExpression="\d*">
```

The above code only validates numbers but not Dash(-). Like user randomly put
23333-34 (should accept) or any combination. It is not must that - will be there. It can be numbers only some times.
Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Must start with one or more number, followed by a possible dash and must end with another number.

```
^\d+\-?\d+$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try accepting number OR dash, and dash only if it is not followed by another dash.

```
(\d|[-](?![-]))*
```

Comment: @user2690007 If you found Adrian's answer helpful and it solved your problem then please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like

```
\d*(-?)
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is something like this:

```
 ^ \d+ (?: - \d+ )+ $
```